# Get distinct values of a record but have other records as well in the select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with timestamp of page views of a particular page by a user. I need to List of unique pages viewd by user and if the user visits same page multiple time I need to fetch the latest record of the lot.

for example: for table tblUserPageViews, i have columns

> PageURL, TimeStamp,UserID,UserPageViewsID

I have tried the obvious

```
SELECT Distinct(PageURL),TimeStamp,UserID,UserPageViewsID FROM tblUserPageViews
```

this will not work

Any ideas much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT PageURL, UserID, UserPageViewsID, MAX(TimeStamp) TimeStamp
FROM tblUserPageViews 
GROUP BY PageURL, UserID, UserPageViewsID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MAX(PageURL),
MAX(TimeStamp),
MAX(UserID),
SUM(UserPageViewsID) 
FROM tblUserPageViews
GROUP BY PageURL
```

Comment: This would fit your need in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try them. I have found this one as well which works well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689567/sql-server-select-top-1-record-of-all-the-distinct-records

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` works in the whole row, not in one particular column. If you need just the userId, pageURL and maximum timestamp, a simple `GROUP BY` is enough:

```
SELECT 
      UserID
    , PageURL 
    , MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
FROM 
      tblUserPageViews 
GROUP BY 
      UserID
```

If you want to show other columns, too, you could use this "wrapping" of the above query into a join with the original table:

```
SELECT
      t.PageURL, 
    , t.TimeStamp
    , t.UserID
    , t.UserPageViewsID
FROM 
      tblUserPageViews AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT 
              UserID
            , PageURL 
            , MAX(TimeStamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
        FROM 
              tblUserPageViews 
        GROUP BY 
              UserID
      ) AS tm
    ON
        tm.UserID = t.UserID 
    AND
        tm.PageURL = t.PageURL
    AND
        tm.MaxTimeStamp = t.TimeStamp
```

If you are on the latest versions of SQL-Server (2005 or later), you could also use [window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to write this.